# Drawing of 2 cylinders with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am not very skilled with tikz. I would like to draw something like this

[image]

So far, by looking at some similar solutions that I found on the web, I could do this

[image]

with the following code

```
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate(C2) at (0,0,0);
  \node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=0.7,minimum height=5cm,minimum     width=2cm,shape border rotate=0] (A) at ($(C2)-(0,0,0)$) {A};

\draw[dashed]
    let \p1 = ($ (A.after bottom) - (A.before bottom) $),
        \n1 = {0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)-\pgflinewidth},
        \p2 = ($ (A.bottom) - (A.after bottom)!0.5!(A.before bottom) $),
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)-\pgflinewidth}
  in
    ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth] A.before bottom) arc [start angle=270, delta angle=180,
    x radius=\n2, y radius=\n1];
    \draw [<->] (A.before top) -- (A.after top) node [midway, above,fill=white] {$2a$};
    
    
\coordinate(C3) at (0,0);
\node [cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=0.7,minimum height=5cm,minimum     width=2cm,shape border rotate=0] (B) at ($(C3)-(+2.7,0,7)$){3};
\draw[dashed]
    let \p1 = ($ (B.after bottom) - (B.before bottom) $),
        \n1 = {0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)-\pgflinewidth},
        \p2 = ($ (B.bottom) - (B.after bottom)!0.5!(B.before bottom) $),
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)-\pgflinewidth}
  in
    ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth] B.before bottom) arc [start angle=270, delta angle=180,
    x radius=\n2, y radius=\n1];
    \draw [<->] (B.before top) -- (B.after top) node [midway, above,fill=white] {$2a$};
    
   \draw[dashed](-3,0)to(3,0);
   %  \draw[dashed](7,0)to(9,0);
   % \draw(0,-0.5)to(0,-1);
    % \draw(7,-0.5)to(7,-1);
     %\draw(0,-0.75)to(2,-0.75);
    % \draw(7,-0.75)to(5,-0.75);
    % \draw[dotted](2,-0.75)to(3.5,-0.75)node[above]{$\ell$}to(5,-0.75);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I need to say, I was "manually" placing one cylinder over the other, and I am not sure I got how they move, really. How can I clearly define the relative position of these two cylinders? Does anyone know how to add the vertical line "h"  and the horizontal line with the "z" ?

Comment: The first cylinder (center) is placed at `(C2)-(0,0,0)` or simply `(0,0)`.  The second at  `(C3) -(+2.7,0,7)` which is simply `(-2.7,0,-7)`.  Why using 3D coordinates here is a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need draw lines and ellipses (or arcs). You also can include the cylinder in a `\foreach` loop so you only have to draw one.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}    
\usepackage    {tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  % dimensions
  \def\a{1}
  \def\h{4}
  \def\z{3}
  % cylinders 
  \foreach\i in {0,\h} % we draw the same figure at heights 0 and \h
  {%
    \draw[red] (-0.5*\z,\i) -- (-0.5*\a,\i);   % axis
    \draw[red,dashed] (-0.5*\a,\i) -- (\z,\i); % axis
    \draw (\z,\i+\a) -- (0,\i+\a) arc (90:270:0.5*\a cm and \a cm) -- (\z,\i-\a) ;
    \draw[dashed] (0,\i-\a) arc (-90:90:0.5*\a cm and \a cm);
    \draw (\z,\i) ellipse (0.5*\a cm and \a cm);
    \draw[red] (\z,\i) -- (1.5*\z,\i); % axis
    \fill[red] (0,\i)  circle (1pt);
    \fill[red] (\z,\i) circle (1pt);
  }
  % auxiliary lines and labels
  \draw[blue,dashed] (\z+0.2,\h+\a)   -- (1.5*\z,\h+\a);
  \draw[blue,dashed] (\z+0.2,-\a)     -- (1.5*\z,-\a);
  \draw[blue,dashed] (0,-\a-0.1)      -- (0,-2*\a)          node [below]        {$z=0$};
  \draw[blue,dashed] (\z,-\a-0.1)     -- (\z,-2*\a)         node [below]        {$z=\ell$};;
  \draw[blue,<->]    (0,-2*\a+0.1)    -- (\z,-2*\a+0.1)     node [midway,below] {$z$};
  \draw[blue,<->]    (1.5*\z-0.1,-\a) -- (1.5*\z-0.1,0)     node [midway,right] {$a$}; 
  \draw[blue,<->]    (1.5*\z-0.1,0)   -- (1.5*\z-0.1,\h)    node [midway,right] {$h$}; 
  \draw[blue,<->]    (1.5*\z-0.1,\h)  -- (1.5*\z-0.1,\h+\a) node [midway,right] {$a$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

will produce:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it looks very nice indeed. I thought that the \node [cylinder etc....] would be easier to use, but what you show is way better and more clear for me. Thanks!